# TidUDPClient thru proxy server

Tags: delphi, proxy, udp, indy

On the below piece of code i have some related questions

```
var
  UseProxy : Boolean = True;
....
var
  IdUDPClient : TIdUDPClient;
  sText       : string;
begin
  IdUDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    IdUDPClient.Host := '10.10.10.10';
    IdUDPClient.Port := 5555;
    if UseProxy then begin
      IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy.Enabled := True;
      IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy.Host    := '20.20.20.20';
      IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy.Port    := 8080;
      IdUDPClient.OpenProxy;
    end;
    try
      IdUDPClient.Connect;
    except
      Writeln('Connect Error.');
    end;
    if IdUDPClient.Connected then
      Writeln('Connected')
    else begin
      Writeln('Not Connected');
      Exit;
    end;
    try
      IdUDPClient.Send('Foo');
      try
        sText := IdUDPClient.ReceiveString(1000);
        Writeln('Received: ', sText);
      except
        Writeln('Receive Error.');
      end;
    except
      Writeln('Send Error.');
    end;
    if UseProxy then
      IdUDPClient.CloseProxy;
  finally
    IdUDPClient.Free;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

1. Why the `try...except` block is not catching errors on the `UDP`
   client even if the Host is not reachable nor the port is closed e.g. `IdUDPClient.Connected` always `True`?
2. When using the proxy i'm not sure if my implementation is correct above
   because if `UseProxy` is True the IdUDPClient try to directly send
   the request to `10.10.10.10`not thru the proxy server. How i can fix this? what i'm doing wrong?

My test scenario for the proxy was as follow:

- My PC IP `30.30.30.30`
- UDP Server `10.10.10.10`
- Proxy Sever (Socks 5) `20.20.20.20`

`30.30.30.0/24` cant reach `10.10.10.10` but `20.20.20.20` does.

3. if my PC can access the UDP server directly and i put fake proxy server (unused IP with random port) to the client. the client can reach the UDP server which is not supposed to be reached because the proxy is down. How i cant prevent such scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. UDP is connection-less, so `Connected` cannot tell you whether the remote peer is reachable or not.

   "Connecting" a UDP socket simply assigns a local association with the peer IP/Port.  That way, outbound packets are sent only to that peer, and only packets received from that peer are accepted.  Nothing more.  There is no actual connection, like in TCP.

   And unlike TCP, sending a UDP packet just dumps the packet onto the network, there is no acknowledgement that the packet ever reaches the peer.  Acks have to be implemented at the application layer.

   As for exceptions, they are only raised when an actual error occurs.  In UDP, the only way an unreachable Host would cause socket errors is if the network sends back an ICMP packet to indicate the Host is not reachable.  A "connected" UDP socket will receive such packets internally and start reporting failures on *subsequent* reads/sends with the same peer.  So, in your example, the call to `Send()` will never raise an error about not being about to reach the Host, because it simply does not know.  `ReceiveString()` has a better chance of reporting such errors, however the way it is currently implemented, it would likely just ignore them because it checks if the socket is readable (has a pending UDP packet) before actually reading it.  A ICMP packet may not make the socket enter a readable state.

   Since you are specifying a timeout on `ReceiveString()`, you will just have to assume the peer is gone if the timeout elapses without receiving an actual string.
2. Your code is bypassing the proxy because you are not setting up the `TransparentProxy` correctly.

   When you access the `TransparentProxy` property, if no proxy component is currently assigned then the property getter creates an internal `TIdSocksInfo` object.  `TIdSocksInfo` has a `Version` property that defaults to `svNoSocks`.  Since you are trying to connect through a SOCKS v5 proxy, you need to set the `Version` to `svSocks5` instead:

   ```
   if UseProxy then begin
     (IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy as TIdSocksInfo).Version := svSocks5; // <--
     IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy.Host    := '20.20.20.20';
     IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy.Port    := 8080;
   end;
   ```

   The `TransparentProxy.Enabled` property setter is not used with `TIdSocksInfo` at all, it is a no-op.  However, the `Enabled` property getter returns True/False depending on the value of the `TIdSocksInfo.Version` property.

   And you don't need to call `OpenProxy()` and `CloseProxy()` manually, `TIdUDPClient.Connect()` and `TIdUDPClient.Disconnect()` will handle that for you when the `TransparentProxy` is enabled.

Now, with all of that said, try this:

```
var
  UseProxy : Boolean = True;
  ...

var
  IdUDPClient : TIdUDPClient;
  IdSocksInfo : TIdSocksInfo;
  sText       : string;
begin
  IdUDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    IdUDPClient.Host := '10.10.10.10';
    IdUDPClient.Port := 5555;

    if UseProxy then begin
      IdSocksInfo := TIdSocksInfo.Create(IdUDPClient);
      IdSocksInfo.Version := svSocks5;
      IdSocksInfo.Host    := '20.20.20.20';
      IdSocksInfo.Port    := 8080;
      IdUDPClient.TransparentProxy := IdSocksInfo;
    end;

    try
      IdUDPClient.Connect;
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        Writeln('Connect Error: ', E.Message);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    try
      Writeln('Connected.');

      try
        IdUDPClient.Send('Foo');
      except
        on E: Exception do begin
          Writeln('Send Error: ', E.Message);
          Exit;
        end;
      end;

      try
        sText := IdUDPClient.ReceiveString(1000);
        if sText <> '' then
          Writeln('Received: ', sText)
        else
          Writeln('Nothing Received after 1 second.');
      except
        on E: Exception do begin
          Writeln('Receive Error: ', E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      IdUDPClient.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    IdUDPClient.Free;
  end;

end.
```

Comment: Hi remy, I get `RSSocksServerCommandError` when calling `IdUDPClient.Connect;` if UseProxy = True;

Comment: `RSSocksServerCommandError` is raised by `TIdSocksInfo` when it receives a reply from a SOCKS v5 proxy containing error code 7 (Command not supported). In this case, `TIdUDPClient.Connect()` sends a SOCKS5 `UDP ASSOCIATE` request, and the server is replying "not supported".  So that is a proxy-side issue.